# select and process columns of text csv

Tags: bash, awk, text, sed

I have a csv text file like

```
2008-01-14T13:38:37.000,10.36,92.7,43.9,C200801141338s,20080114T133837M583Z044
2008-01-16T11:54:44.100,32.35,85.29,12.0,C200801161154d,20080116T115444M589Z012
...
```

It's easy to output the first (datetime) and last two columns with `awk '{print $1,$5,$6}`, but I want to reformat the datetimes, like `2008-01-14T13:38:37.000` to `20080114_133837.x`. How to make it? Thanks.

Comment: Real CSV is actually a pretty complicated format. If this is any kind of important application, you should use a good CSV lib.  I know perl and python have them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  gsub(/-|:/,"",$1)
  sub(/T/,"_",$1)
  sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,".x",$1)
  print $1,$5,$6
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                       ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","                 ##Setting FS, OFS as comma here.
}
{
  gsub(/-|:/,"",$1)          ##Globally substituting - OR : with NULL in $1.
  sub(/T/,"_",$1)            ##Substituting T with _ here in $1.
  sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,".x",$1)   ##Substituting .[0-9]+$ at last of 1st field with .x
  print $1,$5,$6             ##Printing 1st, 5th and 6th fields here.
}
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to do split + join and get this in a single step:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
split($1, a, /[-:.T]+/) >= 6 {
   print a[1] a[2] a[3] "_" a[4] a[5] a[6] ".x", $5, $6
}' file

20080114_133837.x,C200801141338s,20080114T133837M583Z044
20080116_115444.x,C200801161154d,20080116T115444M589Z012
```

Comment: hi @anubhava, what's the meaning of `>= 6`?

Comment: `>=6` can be skipped as well. It just ensures that split function returns at least 6 items in array `a`